# Source for a 6-pin DIL "stackable" header (for Arduino ICSP header)?

Tags: arduino, component-selection, header, icsp

Does anyone know of a source for a "stackable" 6-pin DIL header? I would like to use one on an Arduino shield I am designing, in order to carry the ICSP header from the Arduino up through the shield so it's usable with the shield still installed.

I found [this article](http://www.makechronicles.com/2012/03/10/arduino-project-5-adding-a-stackable-icsp-header-to-the-arduino-ethernet-shield-micro-sdr3-version/) where a more industrious / patient man than myself managed to fabricate a suitable part by cutting up an 8-pin SIL pass-through header with a Dremel tool and a diamond blade. I do have a few of those about, but they're matched in sets for making shields and I don't really want to start cutting them (and probably myself) up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samtec makes them, and surely others. They're pretty expensive though,and take some sifting to find a part number, and more to find someone that stocks them. 
Probably $3+ a piece in small qty, which is too rich for me.

They should be cheaper from the orient, but I don't usually see these being sold to end user / in small quantity, so you'd have to get in touch with someone making connectors there and buy a lot, most likely.

I usually use the no-name Chinese arduino ones like you mention, and just cut them with wire cutters. Diamond disk isn't required.

Comment: I've tried the dremel method now, but using a regular cutting disk and not diamond, like you say. It wasn't too bad, but still seems a waste. If I can find a source I'd consider buying in reasonably quantities and then making them available at cost to like-minded folks in the local area.

Answer (score 0):

I was just searching the smaller variant of this connector and landed on this question.

Here is the Samtec SSQ series: http://cloud.samtec.com/catalog_english/SSQ_TH.PDF